# Is it possible to create an xml and .java file in eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Is there a codes in creating .xml program programmatically and if there was is it possible to copy/retain the codes of the previous .xml? Like I was running my program, clicking the button "new xml" in main.xml and there was a new xml. The codes of it is like the previous main.xml.

I want my program to create xml dynamically as it is running.

same in .java

if there was can it be inputted in a single button and can you provide me with the example of it if you have the program or an explanation?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: You should read some basic tutorials on Android and then ask a well defined question so that we can help you. Your question is very vague as is.

Comment: i'm sorry i know the basic but my explanation is really sucks.

Comment: You can create Java and XML files in Notepad... What specifically are you trying to do? The question makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. If you download the Andorid Development Kit you will be able to File > New > Android project and all the XML files and the default acitivy Java file will be created automatically.

Comment: I want my program to create xml dynamically as it is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your XMLs first, even if they're blank, so that you can programmatically add items onto your view. If you don't have many stuff to change in your view, and you're a beginner, I'd suggest you to keep your current XML and chenge your items in it programmatically (e.g. make a button, some text invisible/visible)

As far as I know, there's no way for you to programmatically add a new `.java` and write stuff onto it *after* your application has been compiled and is running. So you might want to add all of your *behaviour* in your `.java` and think of a logic to use the code you want on certain occasions only.

Cheers and good luck

EDIT AFTER CLARIFICATION OF QUESTION:

Just locate your files in your explorer and do a regular copy and paste of the files you want and rename them to something else.

Comment: I have items in my main.xml. There was this button "new xml" and if i click on it will create new xml and the codes inside it is like in main.xml

Comment: "You should create your XMLs first, even if they're blank, so that you can programmatically add items onto your view." good advice for a beginner, I didn't do it this way and STILL make mistakes as I go! Have a couple of +1s! I've a feeling I'm going to need help on XML myself in a few days ;) @Suprance Do you want your program to create XML dynamically as it is running, or can you just copy and paste your main.xml into another file? I'm not clear still.

Comment: @Suprance no, it will create a blank one.
Just use Finder or Windows explorer, go to the folder where your XMLs are and copy paste it like you would for any file. Eclipse will recognise it after that and will show the file in the project explorer.

Comment: I want my program to create xml dynamically as it is running.
i'm so sorry i can't explain it clearly, I'm having hard time putting my idea into words.

Comment: You can't do that I think (well, I have little experience...). What you may do, on the other hand, is create a blank XML and fill your view after, while it's running. You can't just create a source fileafter the application is built.